# passing ajax associative array to php associative array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, associative

I'm trying to pass form values to PHP via $.ajax method.  I have following form in html:

```
<form>
<p>
   <label for="login">User ID:</label>
   <input type="text" name="login" id="login" value="user name">
</p>

<p>
   <label for="password">Password:</label>
   <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="password">
</p>
</form>
```

and ajax:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
 var formInput = $('form').serialize();// tried with serializeArray() also

 var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"../some.php", 
    data: {formInput:formInput},
    statusCode: {
                404: function() { alert("file not found");}}

 });
```

php:

```
<?
$data = $_POST['formInput'];
$data = array();
parse_str($_POST, $data);
print_r($data);
?>
```

On console it prints:

```
(
     [Array] =>
)
```

What I wanted was for $data to be an associative array as :

```
$data = array(
        'login' => 'foo'
        'password' => 'bar'
        );
```

but it seems like $data is being handled as a string...
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data: $('form').serializeArray()` instead of `data: {formInput:formInput},`

And then in the php side, `$_POST` is just the data you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This works.  I guess data: {formInput: formInput}, puts already serialized array into an array again?! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you need to specify you want an associative array instead of an object from [**json_decode**](http://php.net/json_decode):

```
json_decode($data, true);
```

You might also need to do this -

```
$('form').serializeArray();
```

Comment: .serializeArray() did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

instead of this :

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
 var formInput = $('form').serialize();// tried with serializeArray() also

 var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"../some.php", 
    data: {formInput:formInput},
    statusCode: {
                404: function() { alert("file not found");}}
 });
```

use this :

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
 var formInput = $('form').serialize();// tried with serializeArray() also

 var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"../some.php", 
    data: formInput,
    statusCode: {
                404: function() { alert("file not found");}}
 });
```

Comment: i'm sorry.. but i don't see the difference in the code... am i overlooking something??

Comment: I changed this line : `data: {formInput:formInput},` to this : `data: formInput,`

Comment: works flawlessly with Adil's and Fresh's recommandation of using .serializeArray().  thanks

Answer (score 1):

What we want is to serialize to a json object that can then be decoded. Use [THIS](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object) pluggin to get access to `.serializeObject`.

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
 var formInput = $('form').serializeObject();
 formInput = JSON.stringify(formInput);

 var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"../some.php", 
    data: {formInput:formInput},
    statusCode: {
                404: function() { alert("file not found");}}

 });
```

Then on the php side you can decode the JSON easily

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['formInput'], true);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response.  But, now it prints " </br> " only.  It shows up as null.

Comment: Thank you again for quick response! This was more than what I was looking for.  Really apprciated!!

Comment: @dts316 cool! if this worked for you, please don't forget to hit the checkmark next to my answer so I can get credit.

Answer (score 0):

From great responses I've figured out what my issue was.
When I was submitting POST i was putting array into an array.

the following ajax code:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
var formInput = $('form').serialize();// tried with serializeArray() also

var request = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:"../some.php", 
data: {formInput:formInput},
statusCode: {
            404: function() { alert("file not found");}}
});
```

was changed to:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
var formInput = $('form').serializeArray();

var request = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:"../some.php", 
data: formInput,
statusCode: {
            404: function() { alert("file not found");}}
});
```

And PHP was changed to:

```
<? $data = $_POST;
    print_r($data); ?>
```

on cosole it printed exactly what I wanted:

```
Array
(
[login] => admin
[password] => qwerty123!
)
```

**Thank you everyone for quick responses**